# About 2+1 General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, chern-simons-theory

I'm currently studying on how to write GR as a CS theory, but i have a problem with one of the basic theorem of this subject.

$$ e^\mu_{\ \ a} \epsilon^{\nu \rho \sigma} R_{\ \  \rho \sigma}^a = \det(e) G^{\mu\nu}  $$

And i don't know how to prove. Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Can you expand your question. What is CS theory?

Comment: Chern-Simons , a gauge field theory

Comment: where did you find this theorem and more generally : where are you studying cs theory from?